# Node JS Sequelize v4 generate error while insert data into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

When I try to insert record using Sequelize V4 with node js, this error occurs:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Above error occurred for `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns.

My code is

```
  const School = sequelize.define('school_data', {
  id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true,
      },
  osteo_schl_id: Sequelize.STRING,
  osteo_schl_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  reset_status: Sequelize.STRING,
  last_update_dt: Sequelize.DATE,
});

let data = {
    osteo_schl_id:schoolId,
    osteo_schl_name:schoolName,
    reset_status:0
}

School.create(data);
```

Comment: add timestamps: false in model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#timestamps you can set createdAt and updateAt field as timestamps

```
id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true,
      }
       createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
      updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
```

if you don't need this just set `timestamps:false` to model defenition